# VSC Attach to SSL LocalHost for Angular Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Using the similar launch configuration I'm NOT able to **attach** to http**S**://localhost:4200 from **VSC** for Angular 11 app, neither Chrome nor Edge.

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Edge",
            "port": 9222,
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "pwa-msedge",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to pwa-Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "urlFilter": "https://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Legacy Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "urlFilter": "https://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "F5 against localhost",
            "port": 4201,
            "url": "https://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

> Cannot connect to the target at localhost:9222: Could not connect to
> debug target at http://localhost:9222: Could not find any debuggable
> target.

Bottom `launch` works.

Comment: Same problem for me on attach - not working with SSL

Comment: @Gotts I'm able to nail it, see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have SSL certificate (self or real), `ng serve --ssl` will do.

If still not working then use a diff port. Here is my `launch.json`:

```
{
    "name": "UI Chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "chrome",
    "port": 4201,
    "url": "https://localhost:4200",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

**Update: why 4201?**
`4201` is to help me bypass error in my original debugging, it did the trick help me continue debugging.

Comment: Thanks, @Jeb50. This worked, though I'm puzzled by the `"port"` being `4201` and the port on the `"url"` being `4200`

Comment: @Alex Although my original post was over a year ago, when I did `F5` for debugging, I got err told me `4200` is being used. `4201` did the trick help me continue debugging.